# How to use Variant on component overrided using as props with ChakraUI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chakra-ui

I built a custom Component, and allow it to be re-rendered using as another component using  `BoxProps`:

```
export function Label ({
  children,
  ...boxProps
}:  BoxProps) {

  return (
    <Box {...boxProps}>
      {children}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

It's working well when I try to use the `as={Button}` props

```
<Label as={Button} >ID</Label>
```

But I cannot use the `variant` attribute available on `Button`

```
<Label as={Button} variant={'ghost'}>ID</Label>
                   ^^^^^^^
Property 'variant' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BoxProps'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with `as='button'` ? variant will work with that combination.

Comment: Just tried with `<Label as='button' variant='ghost'>ID</Label>` but got the same error